# How to create a gwt-lib from scratch using tbroyer plugin?

Tags: java, maven, gwt

I'm trying to create a gwt-lib (I gonna call it *gwt-comp*) to store my components and a separated gwt-app (I gonna call it *viewer*) to show them but I'm missing something and don't know what. Both my projects was made with:

```
mvn archetype:generate \
   -DarchetypeGroupId=net.ltgt.gwt.archetypes \
   -DarchetypeVersion=LATEST \
   -DarchetypeArtifactId=modular-webapp
```

The only differences are that I added on their pom:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.2</version>
</plugin>
```

On *viewer*'s pom added *gwt-lib* as dependency with `<type>gwt-lib</type>`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-comp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <type>gwt-lib</type>
</dependency>
```

I did a lot of others changes on my previous tries but deleted the projects and restarted them from the beginning. Could someone please explain to this newbie jr step by step how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A gwt-lib is just a normal jar with `<packaging>gwt-lib</packaging>` and a gwt module name, so just set the packaging, add ltgt plugin with extensions true, and set a module name. here is a sample pom

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.gwtproject.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>test-lib</artifactId>
  <packaging>gwt-lib</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>net.ltgt.gwt.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
          <moduleName>org.gwtproject.test.Lib</moduleName>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```